# How can I test that email was sent after creation of object

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to test that the emails are sent in the after_create callback of an object

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

    #associations
    belongs_to :quotation

  #validations
    validates :method, :amount, :quotation, :presence => true

    #callbacks
    after_create :send_email_confirmations



  def method_enum
     [['Cash'],['Bank Transfer'], ['PayPal']]
  end

  private

  def send_email_confirmations
    UsersMailer.confirm_payment(self).deliver
    AdminsMailer.payment_received(self).deliver
  end

end
```

Test File:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Payment do

    describe AdminsMailer do


        before :each do
            Admin.delete_all
        User.delete_all
        @quotation = FactoryGirl.create(:quotation)
        @submission = @quotation.submission
        @payment = Payment.new(:method => 'paypal', :amount => @quotation.price, :transaction_id => '4543332', :quotation_id => @quotation.id)

        end

        it "should deliver the admin email payment email" do
            @payment.save
            AdminsMailer.should_receive(:payment_received).with(@payment)

        end


    end
end
```

This produces the following result:

```
Failure/Error: AdminsMailer.should_receive(:payment_received).with(@payment)
       (<AdminsMailer (class)>).payment_received(#<Payment id: 54, method: "paypal", amount: #<BigDecimal:7fabd1e449c0,'0.5E3',9(36)>, transaction_id: "4543332", created_at: "2013-09-27 11:30:53", updated_at: "2013-09-27 11:30:53", quotation_id: 58>)
           expected: 1 time
```

How can I test that the emails are sent?

```
received: 0 times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other problems, but you set your expectations after invoking the code under test, so nothing "happened" after that point. You need to either:

1. Move your `should` expectation prior to invoking @payment.save
2. Switch to the `expect { @payment.save }.to receive ...` syntax, or
3. Use the "spies" format (i.e. `should_have_received`)

Comment: I followed your advise. Thanks for sending me on the right path.

Comment: I used Object.any_instance.should_receive(:payment_received) and then

Comment: @payment = Payment.save

Comment: Is there some reason you didn't limit your expectation setting to the actual object you expected to receive the method?